# IIS 10 - web.config - how to enable default document without script access

Tags: web-config, iis-10

We have a folder which contains only static html and images etc. No scripts should be allowed to execute from within this folder. However we would still like to be able to use html default documents.

What is the correct way to configure this?

This is the web.config file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read"/>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="default.html" />
        <add value="default.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I attempt to access http://mysite/mystaticfolder/ it fails with the error...

> HTTP Error 403.1 - Forbidden

However the URL http://mysite/mystaticfolder/default.html works fine.

Surely it shouldn't be nescessary to allow dynamic scripts, just to be able to serve static html default documents?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, I've been able to solve it with the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read">
      <clear/>
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="default.html" />
        <add value="default.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm not entirely sure though why this doesn't work by default though.